# Can't load LLVM bindings in OCaml

Tags: ubuntu, ocaml, llvm

When I `#require "llvm";;` in the OCaml REPL I get:

`Reason: dllllvm.so: dllllvm.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory.`

I'm running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS with all required LLVM deb packages installed from the official LLVM apt repo and the "llvm" OCaml package installed from OPAM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, OCaml bindings to LLVM do not work in the top-level. Disclaimer, I didn't try it myself, I'm just reading the installation script. The installation script contains the following [three lines](https://github.com/ocaml/opam-repository/blob/fa06617553d50b5c97270e16de104ecc70aeee1e/packages/llvm/llvm.4.0.0/files/install.sh#L27-L29):

```
cp "${libdir}"/llvm/*.a $1
mv "${libdir}"/llvm/*.cma $1
mv "${libdir}"/llvm/*.cmxa $1
```

That means, that the shared library is not installed, thus it is not possible to load the llvm library dynamically into the toplevel.

I don't really know whether it is an issue or a limitation, you can try to contact the maintainer, and ask for help/clarification. Use the `opam show llvm | grep author` command, to get his mail address.

It looks like, that the 3.8 version doesn't have this issue, so you can try to install this version (it is available on Xenial), and install the bindings from opam:

```
opam install llvm.3.8
```

An alternative solution for you, would be to build a custom OCaml toplevel. Probably, the easiest way would be to use ocamlbuild for that.